# Is it bad practice to store JSON members with Redis GEOADD?

Tags: laravel, redis

My application should handle a lot of entities (100.000 or more) with location and needs to display them only within a given radius. I basically store everything in SQL but using Redis for caching and optimization (mainly GEORADIUS).

I am adding the entities like the following example (not exactly this, I use Laravel framework with the built-in Redis facade but it does the same as here in the background):

```
GEOADD k 19.059982 47.494338 {\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Foo\",\"address\":\"Budapest, Astoria\",\"lat\":47.494338,\"lon\":19.059982}
```

Is it bad practice? Or will it make a negative impact on performance? Should I store only ID-s as member and make a following query to get the corresponding entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of the requirements. There's nothing wrong with storing the raw data as members as long as it is unique (and it unique given the "id" field). In fact, this is both simple and performant as all data is returned with a single query (assuming that's what actually needed).

That said, there are at least two considerations for storing the data outside the Geoset, and just "referencing" it by having members reflect some form of their key names:

1. A single data structure, such as a Geoset, is limited by the resources of a single Redis server. Storing a lot of data and members can require more memory than a single server can provide, which would limit the scalability of this approach.
2. Unless each entry's data is small, it is unlikely that all query types would require all data returned. In such cases, keeping the raw data in the Geoset generates a lot of wasted bandwidth and ultimately degrades performance.
3. When data needs to be updated, it can become too expensive to try and update (i.e. `ZDEL` and then `GEOADD`) small parts of it. Having everything outside, perhaps in a Hash (or maybe something like [RedisJSON](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisjson)) makes more sense then.